# Можно ли в JS объединить нажатие двух клавиш одновременно

Tags: javascript

Как объединить нажатие двух клавиш одновременно для движения по диагонали?

УВЫ, пример ниже не работает.

```js
let block = document.getElementById("test");
let left = 0;
let top1 = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowRight" && event.key == "ArrowUp") {
    block.style.left = left + "px";
    block.style.top = top1 + "px";
    top1--;
    left++;
  }
};
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Нужно решение на чистом JS.

Comment: _прекрасно знаю, что CANVAS это прекрасно умеет_ - что конкретно умеет canvas?

Comment: @Grundy, я с `canvas` так уж не дружу пока, что-бы конкретно привести пример. Но видел пример, где это реализовано...

Comment: Так что реализовано-то?

Comment: @Grundy, видел пример....  Если я не прав, скажи, к чему наводящие вопросы? ))))

Comment: Пример чего ты видел?

Comment: @Grundy, не  могу найти пример...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86539/discussion-between-grundy-and-air).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея в том, что вам надо хранить состояния кнопок, примерно вот так:

```js
let block = document.getElementById("test");
let left = 0;
let top1 = 0;
let moveRight = false;
let moveDown = false;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowRight") moveRight = true;
  if (event.key == "ArrowDown") moveDown = true;

  block.style.left = left + "px";
  block.style.top = top1 + "px";

  if (moveDown)      top1++;
  if (moveRight)     left++;
};

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "ArrowRight") moveRight = false;
  if (event.key == "ArrowDown") moveDown = false;
};
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```