# Одновременное исполнение двух событий в JS

Tags: javascript

Делаю игру для курсового проекта. Суть игры погрузчик ездит и собирает кубики. Проблема в том, что погрузчик либо поворачивает либо ездит прямо. Одновременно поворачивать и ехать реализовать у меня не получается. Может кто знает как реализовать: при нажатой одной клавише реагировать на нажатие другой, не прекращая обрабатывать событие первой клавиши.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
            if (event.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                this.moveAngle(-5);
            }
            if (event.code === 'ArrowDown')
                this.moveAngle(5);

            if (event.code === 'ArrowLeft') {
                this.turn(-5);
            }
            if (event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
                this.turn(5);
            }
        });

moveAngle(a) {
        this.loader.x += a * Math.cos(this.degrees * Math.PI / 180);
        this.loader.y += a * Math.sin(this.degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    turn(a) {
        if (0 !=
            a) {
            this.degrees %= 360;
            this.degrees += a;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли в JS объединить нажатие двух клавиш одновременно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914804/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-js-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 2):

Схематично

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
   var moveAngle = 0;
            if (event.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                moveAngle -= 5;
            }
            if (event.code === 'ArrowDown')
                moveAngle += 5;
    var turn = 0;
            if (event.code === 'ArrowLeft') {
                turn -= 5;
            }
            if (event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
                turn += 5;
            } 
            this.turn(turn);
            this.moveAngle(moveAngle);
        });
```